# Updating Design Views in Autodesk Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

We've been utilizing Autodesk Viewer to showcase our projects to both our clients and construction teams, and we've encountered some issues that we believe could be improved. Specifically, we rely on the shared link to the Design View, embedding it within our drawings. The challenge we face is that each time we need to make an update, we are required to revise the link across all our drawings. This occurs because, when attempting to upload a new file, a new Design View with a new link must be created, rather than simply updating the existing one while retaining the same link.

A potential solution to streamline this process would be the ability to update an existing Design View with a new file or model, eliminating the need to create an entirely new one with a different link.
Is it possible to do something like this?

Best regards,

Denis Hujdur

We have tried to find a way to update the the Design View without creating a create an entirely new one with a different link, but we discovered that's it's not possible. But if there is a way to go around this, please let us know! :)

Comment: What do you mean by Design View? Are you using Fusion Team or ACC?

Comment: @AdamNagy I'm using Autodesk Viewer which is a free online viewer. After uploading a file to Autodesk Viewer, it's located in the Design Views; https://viewer.autodesk.com/designviews

Answer (score 0):

Just like other services, the [Autodesk Viewer app](https://viewer.autodesk.com/) as well is storing the files in buckets and each version would get a new unique name under the hood - just like in the case of [ACC](https://construction.autodesk.com/) as explained in this blog post:
[File versioning in buckets](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/file-versioning-buckets)

The easiest would be if you used a service like [bitly](https://bitly.com/) or something that you implemented, that could redirect an existing **URL** to **any other URL**. In that case you would only have to update the **URL** there and the links in the drawings could keep using the **same URLs** which could also be **more descriptive**, e.g. [bit.ly/adams-latest-shelf-model](https://viewer.autodesk.com/preview/id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTY5NDA4MDExNF9lM2VlMTk3OC1kNDE0LTRjYjQtYTZhOC1hNzk4NmU5MjczNDcuY29sbGFib3JhdGlvbg).